# Why don't I get the year right using SimpleDateFormat in java?

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat, date-parsing

I trying to parse a data in a `MySql` Format, I ran across `SimpleDateFormat`. I can get the proper day and month, but I got a strange result for the year :

```
date = 2009-06-22;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
Date d = sdf.parse(date);
System.println(date);
System.println(d.getDate());
System.println(d.getMonth());
System.println(d.getYear());
```

Outputs :

```
2009-06-22
22           OK
5            Hum... Ok, months go from 0 to 11
109          o_O WTF ?
```

I tried changing the format to `YYYY-MM-dd` (got an error) and `yy-MM-dd` (did nothing). I am programming on Android, don't know if it's important.

For now, I bypass that using a split, but it's dirty and prevent me from using i18n features.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The year is relative to 1900. That's a "feature" of the `Date` class. Try to use `Calender`.

Comment: OK, got it. I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Aaron, the right version :

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
c.setTime(sdf.parse(date));
System.println(c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

The existing answers have already explained correctly how `java.util.Date` returns the year relative to 1900 and how you can get around the problem by using `java.util.Calendar`.

The question and existing answers use `java.util` date-time API and `SimpleDateFormat` which was the correct thing to do in 2009. In Mar 2014, the `java.util` date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` were supplanted by the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html). Since then, it is highly recommended to stop using the legacy date-time API.

### Using `java.time`, the modern date-time API:

**You do not need a `DateTimeFormatter`:** `java.time` API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and therefore you do not need a `DateTimeFormatter` to parse a date-time string which is already in ISO 8601 format e.g. your date string, `2009-06-22` which can be parsed directly into a `LocalDate` instance which contains just date units.

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String strDateTime = "2009-06-22";
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(strDateTime);
        System.out.println(date);
        System.out.printf("Day: %d, Month: %d, Year: %d", date.getDayOfMonth(), date.getMonthValue(), date.getYear());
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2009-06-22
Day: 22, Month: 6, Year: 2009
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/jItC0n)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.