# Why getCalendar().getTime() returns wrong Year?

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

Why code

```
Date time1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.US).getCalendar().getTime();
```

return wrong year?

> Mon Dec 12 08:49:57 GMT+03:00 1938

Why is **1938**?

Comment: It's not a duplicate of the link provided by you, his question is "WHY" is it returning the wrong year, not "how to?"

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Because `SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.US).getCalendar()` has something to do with Serialization which causes the problem

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1258657/8164116)

Use

```
Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
```

Comment: instead of answering a question that is a duplicate with an answer from the duplicated question, you should just mark the question as duplicate, and not copy (partially in your question) the other answer

Comment: Makes sense! I'll keep that in my mind. Thanks!

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko But again, defining "possible duplicates" doesn't really solve his problem. I wonder why people downvoted my answer, lol!

Comment: “Has something to do with serialization” doesn’t really answer the question either. If you believe that a separate answer to this question is warranted, I think you should at least give a full answer. Link-only answers are discouraged (which I hope you have heard before).

Comment: I totally agree with you, but copying and pasting the whole explanation is kinda redundant, what he was actually looking for a solution. I'm not saying that I'm correct, but if my answer solved his problem, why bother downvoting it? :/

Comment: But yes, I support you point and I won't repeat it again :)

Comment: Since you ask and since answers are just as much for future readers as for the asker, I do see the point in downvoting (and even flagging for deletion) incomplete answers (I haven’t downvoted, and no one has flagged).